# is possible to set and modify a date object in one line on javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to do this:

```
oneYearBefore = new Date();
oneYearBefore.setFullYear(oneYearBefore.getFullYear() - 1);
```

or any other way that give-me a date object setted one year before. Its for using like this (without creating the var):

```
formatDate(new Date().setFullYear(oneYearBefore.getFullYear() - 1));
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/01ppmjgk/

Comment: `formatDate((new Date()).setFullYear((new Date()).getFullYear() - 1));`

Comment: this don't make sense, my formatDate function don't return a Date instance

Comment: I posted something to answer to your question, what `formatDate` does I don't even know.

Comment: (new Date()).setFullYear((new Date()).getFullYear() - 1) isn't a instance of Date too

Comment: That is because the returned value comes from `setFullYear()` and not from the `new Date()`. To get a date instance it should be `(new Date((new Date()).setFullYear((new Date()).getFullYear() - 1)))`

Comment: Anyway, I don't recommend this practice. Next week if you will have to change this code, you will lose some minutes to understand it.

Comment: `new Date(new Date().getTime() - 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` ?

Comment: this version is better